# SSD: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, chkdsk

I am running Windows 10 with all the latest updates installed. I was having issues with Visual Studio 2017. So I uninstalled and now wish to reinstall it.

The installer complained that I needed to have

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise

Empty before proceeding with the new installation. So I went to delete whatever was in that folder, but I get the following:

[image: error]

I googled and people are saying I should run `chkdsk` command, but as far as I know, that's really bad for an SSD? My whole drive is SSD and I don't want to mess that up in any way.

Any help and advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "*as far as I know, that's really bad for an SSD*" Huh? Where did that come from?

Comment: From questions [such as this](https://superuser.com/questions/209606/how-safe-is-it-to-run-chkdsk-on-an-ssd)

Comment: Dude, that's like seven years old. Modern SSDs have almost nothing in common with those. And even back then you find this comment, "with the newest breed of SSDs I'm sure that there's very little to worry about. But with the first generation or two of SSDs there were many pitfalls that people were worried about (though not necessarily any actual problems)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `chkdsk`. From an elevated `cmd` prompt, type `chkdsk /f c:`. It will probably ask you to reboot.

I have no idea what you might possibly mean by that being "bad" for an SSD or why you might think that. But if you have a possibly corrupt filesystem (and you do), you need to repair it. It's really that simple.

Comment: Thanks, I did as you suggested, and that fixed it! I was then able to delete the file.