# Check files integrity

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, filesystems

The advice found on most sites is when you lose power on your PC, the best way to check files integrity for corruption is to check whether they are readable or not since `chkdsk` does it for the file system but not individual files (`chkdsk /r` might do it but it is bad for an SSD) . For videos files I use [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/100288/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-video-file-avi-mpeg-mp4), but what about other files, ideally it would be checking them against checksums such as `MD5` or `SHA-1`. In the case of their non availability, is there any tool or PowerShell command that can do this for hundreds of files, also open if such command is available for Linux.

Comment: Use Btrfs and [just read the files](https://superuser.com/a/1285549/432690).

Comment: Why would `chkdsk /r` be bad on a SSD? Even if it were, you'd have to do it anyway.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/209606/how-safe-is-it-to-run-chkdsk-on-an-ssd. Problems with `chkdsk /r` are rare, and if you end up being one of those rare people, `chkdsk /f` will fix it.

Comment: `Sfc /scannow` is probably what you're after.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala sfc will check the system files, I want to check my personal non system files.